# Yii1 - prevent pagination (dataProvider) from counting, or cache it

Tags: yii, yii1.x

Is it possible to prevent counting in the data provider, or at least cache the result?

This is my current code, and the count is done on every call:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(PProjectJob::model()->cache(3600, null, 2), array(
            'criteria' => $searchForm->search(),
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
            ),
            'sort' => RedeliverySearchForm::getSort(),
            'totalItemCount' => null
        ));
```

Initial query is always the same, and caching a count result will for 24 hours will have a great impact on performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `'totalItemCount'` value into the [CActiveDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) constructor, which you have passed in as `null` in your current code

The data provider will only run a count query if its `'totalItemCount'` is `null`

You could happily calculate, or fetch from cache, the count result yourself, based on the `$searchForm->search()` criteria, and pass it in

A second option is to create your own extension of CActiveDataProvider, override `calculateTotalItemCount()`, and provide a caching option for the count result where it currently runs the `count()` query